# How to wrap dictionary type in c# with bracket

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a method in controller in asp.net mvc for return json object like this:

```
    [AllowCrossSiteJson]
    public ActionResult Cost()
    {
        var response = new Dictionary<string, int>();
        var licenses = licenseRepository.AllLicenses();
        licenses.ForEach(license =>
        {
            response[license.name] = license.cost;
        });
        return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

that's the simple method that return json object like this:

```
{
    "foo": 1500000,
    "bar": 1200000,
}
```

but I want some thing like this:

```
[{
    "foo": 1500000,
    "bar": 1200000,
}]
```

How can I reach?

Comment: Try `return Json(new [] {response}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);`

Comment: that's worked thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square brackets indicate an array, so you should be able to get the JSON you want with this:

```
return Json(new [] {response}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just wrap it in an array.

You can also simplify the code a bit using LINQ:

Something like this:

```
[AllowCrossSiteJson]
public ActionResult Cost()
{
  var licenses = licenseRepository
                 .AllLicenses()              // fetch the enumerable list of licenses from the repository
                 .ToDictionary(              // and convert each license into a dictionary
                   license => license.name , // key selector
                   license => license        // value selector
                 );
  Dictionary<string,int>[] response = { licenses };

  return Json(response, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```